# Finding the Real part of tan(z) or tan(x+iy)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that $~\Re\left(\tan(z)\right) =\dfrac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)+\sinh^2(y)}~~$ (where $z=x+iy$)

I have solved for it using trigonometric identities and some simple algebra but I've only reached so far:

$$\Re\left(\tan(z)\right)=\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y) + \sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y)}$$

And I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Use the Pythagorean Identity $$\cosh^2 y = \sinh^2 y + 1 .$$